# How to show Bootstrap Modal with busy icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose when user clicks on a button then I would like to show Bootstrap dialog with busy icon just like below one with small size. When server side content comes, requested by jQuery AJAX, then Bootstrap dialog will be automatically resized with bit of animation to fit the content data. Please guide me how to achieve it with Bootstrap Modal and jQuery.

[image: preview]

I searched Google a lot to have this kind of Bootstrap dialog but found no concept.

Comment: So you want to click on the button to open a modal and load informations with ajax and after loading displaying them in the modal

Comment: when user click on button then small bootstrap modal will be opened with busy icon and when server side content will come then busy icon will go and content will be set inside bootstrap modal.

Comment: Okay I've got a similar problem a while ago and solved it with https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ which looks fine with bootstrap 4

Comment: I edited your question to change some grammar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the loader icon this way:

1. Inside the `.modal-body`, add this content:

   ```
   <img src="loading.gif" />
   ```
2. When you click on the link, you fire an AJAX and update the content of the `.modal-body`.

If you are using events, you can use:

```
$(document).on("show.bs.modal", function () {
  $(".modal-body").html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
});
```

You can start with something of that sort and continue working on this.

Comment: How do you know that his loader is a (animated) gif?

Comment: what is show.bs.modal ? what kind of event you are attaching with on keyword?

Comment: @Thomas Check this out: https://gist.github.com/Simsso/6f1c46b432443aaf7d5b70d13418fcc4

Comment: @chade_ Assuming `loading.gif` is a GIF animation similar to shown one - Common sense.

Comment: @Soolie Sounds more legit to me now. +1

Comment: Thanks @chade_... `:)`